# JSON Date without eval?

Tags: javascript, json, date

**Short description:**

Is there a javascript JSON-converter out there that is able to preserve Dates and does **not** use eval?
Example:

```
var obj1 = { someInt: 1, someDate: new Date(1388361600000) };
var obj2 = parseJSON(toJSON(obj1));
//obj2.someDate should now be of type Date and not String
//(like in ordinary json-parsers).
```

**Long description:**

I think most people working with JSON already had the problem of how to transmit a Date:

```
var obj = { someInt: 1, someDate: new Date(1388361600000) }
```

When converting this to JSON and back, the date suddenly became a String:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) 
== { someInt: 1, someDate: "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z" }
```

This is a huge disadvantage since you cannot easily submit a Date using JSON. There is always some post-processing necessary (and you need to know where to look for the dates).

Then Microsoft found a loophole in the specification of JSON and - by convention - encodes a date as follows:

```
{"someInt":1,"someDate":"\/Date(1388361600000)\/"}
```

The brilliance in this is that there is a now a definitive way to tell a String from a Date inside a valid JSON-string: An encoded String will **never** contain the substring @"/" (a backslash followed by a slash, not to be confused with an escaped slash). Thus a parser that knows this convention can now safely create the Date-object.

If a parser does not know this convention, the date will just be parsed to the harmless and readable String "/Date(1388361600000)/".

The huge drawback is that there seems to be no parser that can read this without using eval. Microsoft proposes the following way to read this:

```
var obj = eval("(" + s.replace(/\"\\\/Date\((\d+)\)\\\/\"/g, function (match, time) { return "new Date(" + time + ")"; }) + ")");
```

This works like a charm: You never have to care about Dates in JSON anymore. But it uses the very unsafe eval-method.

Do you know any ready-to-use-parser that achieves the same result without using eval?

**EDIT**
There was some confusion in the comments about the advantages of the tweaked encoding.
I set up a jsFiddle that should make the intentions clear: http://jsfiddle.net/AJheH/

Comment: JSON is a notation for strings, it doesn't hold actual objects.

Comment: Ugh. It sucks that Date is not a native JSON type, but that “trick” is ugly. I would avoid like the plague. You have to manually convert dates on other platforms regardless. I don’t see the point in using the loophole unless you are only ever going to deploy on IE.

Comment: The eval-parsing works perfectly fine in all browsers. This has nothing to do with IE.

Comment: What's wrong with using iso8601 formatted strings?

Comment: @Remco: They are strings and not dates. Thus you need to parse them manually when you want to use them.

Comment: @Andreas: sure, but JSON is designed to be a very simple, very neutral, universal syntax for data. I’m not sure there’s a simpler, more neutral, more universal syntax for dates than ISO8601 strings.

Comment: @Paul: Just compare the effort to work with the results when working on an application. In one case you need to remember parsing them on each access, in the other case you just have the date ready to use. IMO dates are way too common to sacrifice the simple handling for the sake of simplicity of the data format.

Comment: @Andreas: It would be easier for the JSON consumer if the JSON spec had a specified date format, and every JSON library parsed those dates into their language’s date object. I can think of two problems: 1. What if the language in question didn’t *have* a built-in date object? 2. What syntax would you use to indicate dates in JSON, that wouldn’t conflict with other data? Personally, I’d rather store dates in JSON as ISO8601 strings — handling those in code is never likely to be problematic, because ISO8601 is the established standard.

Comment: @Paul: A possible syntax is the one used by MS: It does not conflict with anything else, it is to some extend backwards-compatible since someone not knowing the syntax will get a parsable string and it is extensible: you can put different types into the JSON-notation by replacing the keyword "Date" with something else and providing different parameters inside the brackets.

Comment: @Andreas: yeah, true true.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with adeno's comment that JSON is a notation for strings and cannot represent objects. Json is a notation for compound data types which must be in the form of a serialized objects, albeit that the primitive types can only be integer, float, string or bool. (update: if you've ever had deal with spaghetti coded XML, then you'll appreciate that maybe this is a good thing too!)

Presumably hungarian notation has lost favour with Microsoft if they now think that creating a  non-standard notation incorporating the data type to describe a type is better idea.

Of itself 'eval' is not evil - it makes solving some problems a lot easier - but it's very difficult to implement good security while using it. Indeed it's disabled by default with a Content Security Policy.

IMHO it boils down to storing the date as 1388361600000 or "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z". IMHO the latter has significantly more semantic value - taken out of context it is clearly a date+time while the latter could be just about anything. Both can be parsed by the ECMAscript Date object without resorting to using eval. Yes this does require code to process the data - but what can you do with an sort of data without parsing it? he only time I can see this as being an advanage is with a schemaless database - but in fairness this is a BIG problem.

Comment: About the format: It does not just boil down to using "ms since 1970" or an ISO string. You can do both in both formats (in MS-case just replace the number between the brackets with the ISO string and update the regex to create the call to the constructor accordingly).

Comment: About typing: It's basically a matter of comfort. I enjoy working in an environment that does the simple tasks for me. And I do really think that transmitting a date from A to B should be a simple task :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following line of code, here is an example function and take a look at parseWithDate function, add the script to the page and change the following line to this it will work.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_serialize_dates_to_json.ashx

```
var parsed1 = JSON.parse(s1); // changed to below
var parsed1 = JSON.parseWithDate(s1);
```

Updated jsFiddle that works http://jsfiddle.net/GLb67/1/

Comment: This is just a parser for the string, but does not solve the issue of creating dates directly from the JSON-String. Unsing MomentJs, instead of getting all the Dates as Dates directly, I need to traverse the object-tree after parsing the JSON and convert each Date manually (and I have to know where they are, since "/Date(1198908717056)/" might also actually be a string. There is no need for this step in the approach I mentioned above.

Comment: Write your own reviver for the json parse, its simple and you have all the pieces. 
There is the definition of the json parse https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

And here is an example of a reviver that will parse a date
https://gist.github.com/jcbozonier/1692807

Comment: The revivers come too late, since the "\" is already removed. What should a reviver do when it gets the string "/Date(1198908717056)/"? There is no way to tell if this was originally a Date or a String (nobody keeps the user from entering this into some form field).

Comment: After goggling around i found the perfect the solution. Check the answer above.

Comment: Sorry, using this, you have the opposite issue: In some cases strings will turn into dates. Check http://jsfiddle.net/GLb67/2/. I just added an unfortunate string to the object before stringifying it. And the method "stringifyWcf" is wrong as well, since it does not add the necessary "\".